# Add a word in front if it is not in the sentence in C#

Tags: regex

I think this problem can be done with regex. But unfortunately I am not good in regex. I have a sentence now I want to add 'OBSBOT' in front if it is not in the sentence

Example: **Input**: UVC to HDMI Adapter

**Output will be**: OBSBOT UVC to HDMI Adapter

I have found some solutions but these don't solve my problem. I have tried with the below way. But it gives me output like this: `OBSBOT OBSBOT HQ Mic`

```
string resultOutput = new Regex("^(?!.*OBSBOT)|^(OBSBOT)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
.Replace("OBSBOT HQ Mic", "OBSBOT $1");
```

N.B: I want to be able to input multiple sentences.

**Update: Input:**

```
UVC to HDMI Adapter  
OBSBOT HQ Mic
Remote controller for Tiny 4K 
HQ Mic OBSBOT
HQ OBSBOT Mic
```

**Output:**

```
OBSBOT UVC to HDMI Adapter  
OBSBOT HQ Mic
OBSBOT Remote controller for Tiny 4K  
HQ Mic OBSBOT
HQ OBSBOT Mic
```

**Note:**

Previously, all tasks on the sentence were performed using a regular expression, and I would not want to add new code to the programming language using other mechanisms.

I want to find a solution through regex using it in full force.

Comment: I think I found the solution myself ^(?!.*OBSBOT)|^(OBSBOT)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the expression:

```
^(?!.*OBSBOT)
```

And replace this with

```
OBSBOT
```

**See [a demo on regex101.com.](https://regex101.com/r/Vt3TKK/1)**

Answer (score 1):

You could use the expression:

```
^(?!OBSBOT)(.+)
```

And replace this with

```
OBSBOT $1
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/K3BdsW/1).

Comment: this solution will not work if, for example, you flip : HQ Mic OBSBOT

Comment: the task is to add a word in front if it is not in the sentence